# Making emacs keyboard shortcuts like windows

Tags: emacs

i spent a lot of time and i am super productive makimg my muscle memory work well navigating text files on windows. Now that i am on emacs, I see my productivity drop severely.

for example, in Visual Studio to move to the next word you type Ctrl + right arrow, and to the prev Ctrl + left arrow. I both think that this is more natural than M-b and M-f and it's easier because it's what other systems use (think, word docs, or text boxes when typing an email or a Stack question).

Is there a simple way to configure the emacs keyboard shortcuts to map to the ones from other systems?

Comment: Doesn't Ctrl+Arrow work in Emacs too? I use that and I don't use M-F, M-b either. Are you using the latest emacs? Version 24?

Comment: I've been using Ctrl+Right and Ctrl+Left in Emacs as far back as I can remember without any special setup required.

Comment: As others commented, the basic navigation keys like Ctrl+Right should work out-of-box. Also you can enable CUA mode for select and cut/copy/paste semantics. That will help your Windows-centric muscle memory. (Re "what other systems use": Just FYI, people who move among Windows/cygwin, Mac, and Linux have an alternate muscle memory investment. :) Depends what circles you travel in.)

Comment: After years of using Emacs, at one point I actually turned off the arrow keys to force myself learning the "classic" keybindings to move the point. There was actually no point to that exercise, it was just for fun. However, I do find it beneficial now when using Emacs on my netbook where the arrow keys are tiny. Also, I use Emacs almost exclusively in terminal mode and depending on the terminal, the combination of modifier+arrow key may not even work, so it's good to have the traditional keybinding in my muscle memory now. Still, sometimes some edits can be done quicker with the arrow keys.

Comment: They don't work on mine. I guess the problem could be that I am using emacs over Putty, so not sure if this shortcut is more from the shell itself. Anyways, I'm moving to a mac soon so it's great to know it works. i can see also that no one uses the old school key bindings, i knew they where dumb. Thanks

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark your link shows how to put emacs key bindings into VS, but I want a solution the other way around, VS key bindings in emacs.

Comment: @JorgeGuzman play around with the keyboard mapping settings in putty. I also use emacs over putty, and the arrow keys work fine. This question might be useful too: https://superuser.com/questions/94436/how-to-configure-putty-so-that-home-end-pgup-pgdn-work-properly-in-bash

Comment: modifier + arrow keysdepend on how your terminal is setup from your profile. This is one of the first things i do: add ctrl + arrow word jumping in the terminal.